# Get application username for Audit table

Tags: c#, sql-server, audit, multi-user

I want to implement an audit table and I have no idea how am I supposed to get the username.

I am using C# and Sql Server. I have a Users table in my database. When I log in my windows form application I verify if the correct combination of username and password is used. But how do I inform the database of the current user? I thought of adding an extra column to my Users table in which to set on 1 the logged username. Is that a solution for single-user? But my application in supposed to support multi-user. What could be done in this case?

Comment: Are your users Windows/AD user accounts? Or are the application specific users (i.e. defined in a Users table in your database or something along those lines)? 

What authentication method are you using to connect to the DB? Are you using windows authentication or do you have a specific DB user/password combo?

Comment: They are application specific users and I suppose what I want is a specific DB user/password combo..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @username varchar(128)
    SET @username = CONVERT(VarChar(128), CONTEXT_INFO());
    PRINT @username
    DECLARE @ID_User int
    SET @ID_User = ( SELECT Users.ID_User
                       FROM Users
                         WHERE Users.Username=@username )
    PRINT @ID_User
```

This is how I solved it. I inserted this piece of code in each update trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your authentication scheme, you need to get the the User name.

for thick client applications,

```
Environment.Username
```

and

```
System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent()
```

are a couple of options.

typically for audit tables, there is a column called 'ModifiedByUser' where you can log the user name provided by the win form app.

1. create the nvarchar and datetime columns (if not already) in your audit table.
2. one will stored the user name and the other the datetime of the audit action.
3. in your code, whenever you want to add an entry to the audit table, get Environment.Username or System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent(), along with DateTime.UtcNow and pass it on to be saved to the DB  into the Audit table.

Comment: When you said authentication scheme you mean NTLM or Kerberos? (I just found out that these are used on sql-server). Could you please provide an example of how ModifiedByUser column works or could you be a little more specific about it? (The audit table is also created by me.)

Comment: Thanks for the update. This works for Windows user accounts. But for application specific users(stored in a database table), what could be done?

Comment: can you explain more? what do you mean by application specific user here?

Comment: I mean my database has a table, Users. When I log to my Windows Forms App I check if the user and the password match any record of that table. I want the field username from that record to be the one inserted in the Audit table.

Comment: Oh okay. In that case the windows form app should always store the username of the logged in user in memory and use that to save it to the db.

Comment: I could do so, but how do I link the username of the logged in user with the other fields which are automatically filled by a trigger?

Comment: INSERT or UPDATE trigger? and how is it invoked? you need to have the username passed in from the app into the DB (some table/row) for the trigger to use.

Comment: It's invoked on update, only for columns whose value were changed. It appears that the username could be passed from the application to the trigger using CONTEXT_INFO(). Is there any other way?

Comment: if the username is not part of the original table row being updated, then yes, you need to use context info for the trigger to get it.. go ahead

Comment: I can't put code in comment, so I'll post an aswer. I'm getting trouble when using CONTEXT_INFO.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server knows who you are. You can simply use `SUSER_SNAME()` or/and `ORIGINAL_LOGIN()` function as a default value for the username column in your audit table. Same for the time of audit event, use `GetDate()` function. There is no need to send this information from the client.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very open-ended question but I think I understand what you are trying to do. You have application-specfic users that are defined in a Users table (as opposed to using database users or active directory users) and you need to log specific information for auditing purposes or drive security based off of the logins. Is that correct?

This can be done, but the logic for it will need to be written in your application.

Let’s pretend we are writing a program to send out an invoice to a customer.
I used role based security where you can give users access to do specific tasks by granting them a role. For example, “Create New Invoice” could be a role. I usually have 2 tables for this:

1. SecuirtyRoleDefintion
2. SecurityRoleUsers

The fist table, *Security Role Definition* will have an ID column, the Description (“Create New Invoice”), and I usually have a Audit column to indicate if this action needs to be logged for Audit.

The second table, *SecurityRoleUsers*, is where I define if a user has permission to execute that role. Columns are usually something like this: a unique ID, User ID (foreign key to the *Users* table), RoleID (foreign key to *SecurityRoleDefintion*)

Now in your application we need a class to check if a user has a role. It needs to take in the role ID (or name) and the user ID. Example: `public bool IsUserAuthorized(int RoleID, int UserID)`

This method can run a query on your *SecurityRoleUsers* table to see if the user is in the table for that role. If so, it returns true. If not, it returns false.

Now back in the application when user click the “Create New Invoice” button it runs the *IsUserAuthorized()* method to check if a user can perform the operation.

If creating an audit log is necessary, you could do something similar. After the security check is done for “Create New Invoice” you can check to see if the Role needs to be audit logged, if so then write to an Audit table.

Comment: i do have these tables, and i have implemented functions to check user's permissions. my problem was how to pass the current username to my audit table, for a multiuser application. it appears that CONTEXT_INFO works(current username is inserted), but because i haven't installed the app on multiple devices, i am not sure how it will behave.